# Conditional optimization in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-construction, visual-studio-debugging

I have a code like this:

```
void f()
{
  //Some function I want to debug
  g();
  //More code
}
void g()
{
  //A very slow function I want to have optimized for performance
  //No debugging this code
}
```

Where **f** is whatever function in my code I want to debug and **g** is a function computationally intensive.

When I compile the code with *Release* configuration, both pieces of code get optimized and it all runs in a reasonable time, but when I compile with *Debug* configuration, then **g** takes way too long to execute as the compiler don't optimize the code to keep it debugger-friendly.

I don't need to deal with **g** from a debugging point of view and can not extract it into a pre-compiled module (it's under active development and need to keep it up to date). They are defined in different files.

*Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to compile **g** for speed, while keeping **f** compiled using Debug configuration?*

Comment: How do you know that you don't need to debug `g()`?

Comment: You can use `#pragma optimize` directive.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It's been tested and validated independently, so debugging it is not relevant for the development of **f**, so I just want to have it as an optimized black box.

Comment: Why do you want to debug `f`? Can't  you stub out `g` and test `f`?

Comment: @doctorlove: Stubbing is probably the way to go, at least from the testing-point-of-view. The question comes more from curiosity on how to compile different sections of the code with a different compilation configuration each (optimization levels or whatever). I liked the #pragma approach as Alex commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either move `f` into another compilation unit, e.g. another file or [`#pragma optimize`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/chh3fb0k.aspx) The latter is probably the better choice because it's harder to forget you set that up than changing the compilation settings on a particular file, which you would have to remember to go back and reset.

Or you could just profile in debug mode and see what's happening. As VS Premium and above include these tools that shouldn't be too hard, or you can use a third party tool. Profiling usually gives a really good idea of what's the true cause of any slowdown.

Comment: #pragma optimize is what I was looking for. I've used the profiler before, but I'm not really analyzing performance now. Thanks

Comment: Credit where credit is due @AlexFarber is the one who pointed it out, I had seen it before but forgotten about it.